# Just moved in and want to hook up Nest/Google thermostats but need C wire

Tags: wiring, thermostat-c-wire

I’m trying to figure out which wire(s) are my Common so that I can set up my Google thermostats. I don’t have one used right now, just 2 wires for my four thermostats.  I need to connect the 2wire to 3wire adapter but I need a spot for my Common.  This is what I have:

[image]

And on the other side this:

[image]

The guy I bought it from was crrrraaaazzzyy into wiring cameras, monitors etc everywhere. The stuff on the right was running to a whole control set but has been removed except for wiring. So do I lift the black from one of the left side, the right side, or none of the above?

Comment: What make and model is that control box the terminal block in your photos is connected to?

Comment: Look for the 24 V transformer. The common wire comes from it

Comment: brands and models of all equipment involved will be _most_ helpful.

Comment: If you remove your thermostat, how many conductors total are in the wire? You said you had two wires but is that literally two wires in the cable or just two wires being used by the old thermostat? Is this a heat-only radiator, hydronic, or similar system?

Answer (score 0):

Step one: Look for the 24 V transformer. The common wire comes from it –

Since the wire colors mean nothing and the labels are not familiar to me, but maybe make sense in Lebanon, I would guess the common is the part of the bundle where you can connect it for the thermostat. I marked it with yellow circle.

[image: com]

Comment: Would I not pull the 24v from the other side? It is labeled the 5th from the bottom.

Comment: The transformer has 2 tabs, one is for 24 Volt output the other is for common. If you have multimeter check from each to the ground (chassis) one will show 24 volt the other will show zero volt

Comment: I think this side looks like the power connections, and the other side looks like the control terminals, given how they are labeled (and that they are labeled at all, and that they have status lights). The Z +zone) terminals would not be Common. 24 V shouldn't be. I'm not sure about the others -- but it's possible that common is on a completely separate terminal. (It is in my Munchkin).